# Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis Theorem 2.14 Question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

$\mathbf{Theorem 2.14:}$
Let $A$ be the set of all sequences whose elements are the digits $0$ and $1$. Then A is uncountable, meaning there does not exist a one-to-one mapping of A onto $\mathbb{Z}$.

For reference, elements of $A$ have this form $(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,\cdots)$

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Please bear with me. I know I'm wrong I don't know why. What is wrong with this logic?

Let $E_1$ be the set containing all the sequences with just one $1$ in the sequence. i.e. $E_1 = \left\{(1,0,0,\cdots),(0,1,0,0,\cdots),(0,0,1,0,0,\cdots),\cdots\right\}$. $E_1$ is countable.

Let $E_{2k}$ be the set containing all the sequences with only two $1$'s in the sequence where the next $1$ in the sequence is $k$ units next to the first $1$.

$E_{21} = \left\{(1,1,0,\cdots),(0,1,1,0,0,\cdots),(0,0,1,1,0,0,\cdots),\cdots \right\}$
$E_{22} = \left\{(1,0,1,0,\cdots),(0,1,0,1,0,\cdots),(0,0,1,0,1,0,\cdots),\cdots \right\}$

Let the union of the sets $E_{2k}$ for ($k=1,2,3,\cdots$) be called $E_2$. $E_2$ is countable.

Let $E_{3ij}$ be the set of sequences with only three $1$'s where the second $1$ is $i$ units away from the first $1$, and the third $1$ is $j$ units away from the second.

For example:

$E_{311} = \left\{(1,1,1,0,\cdots),(0,1,1,1,0,\cdots),(0,0,1,1,1,0,\cdots),\cdots\right\}$
$E_{312} = \left\{(1,1,0,1,\cdots),(0,1,1,0,1\cdots),(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,\cdots)\cdots\right\}$
$E_{322} = \left\{(1,0,1,0,1,\cdots),(0,1,0,1,0,1,0\cdots),(0,0,1,0,1,0,1\cdots)\cdots\right\}$
$E_{333} = \left\{(1,0,0,1,0,0,1\cdots),(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,\cdots),(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,\cdots)\cdots\right\}$

Let $E_3$ be the union of all the sets $E_{3ij}$ with ($i,j=1,2,3,\cdots$).
Since each $E_{3ij}$ is countable the union of them is countable, so $E_3$ is countable.

The zero sequence is just one sequence, $E_1$ is countable, $E_2$ is countable, $E_3$ is countable. Now if we continue defining the sets in this manner then each set $E_k$ (where $k$ is the number of $1$'s in the sequences) will be a countable set.

So, the union of all these sets will be countable and it will represent all the sequences in A.

Thank you in advance to anyone who reads all of this and answers!

Comment: I am thinking of an answer, but full marks for the attempt of your own. +1. Turns out you do not account for infinitely many ones.

Comment: What if there are infinitely many ones ?

Comment: We've all had moments where being intelligent smart people we *know* are results are wrong but don't see our errors.  There's no harm in asking implicitely but subtly hidden errors of the countably infinite for finite are a very easy mistake to make.  Even for experienced mathematicians.  Points to the OP for seriously making an effort.

Comment: Since most people don't have Rudin memorized, how about you put the actual question in the title, and the reference in the body for context?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Interesting, I remember Theorem 2.14 for Rudin's real and complex analysis, which is [Riesz representation theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509109/questions-on-theorem-2-14-rudin-real-complex-analysis). I guess quite a number of analyst remember that too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your union of $E_{ijk\cdots}$ does not contain the following element

$$(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1, \cdots).$$

Indeed those $E$'s contain elements in $A$ with finitely many nonzero entries. You have just proved:

> The subset of $A$ consisting of all sequences with finitely many $1$'s is countable.

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much for taking the time to show that to me, I really appreciate that!